# How to add schema markup to WordPress menu function

Tags: functions

I would like to add to my main nav items and it seems like the only way to do that is by changing the menu function. Below is the structure I am trying to implement:

```
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
  <li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="domain.com">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the function that generates the main menu:

```
   // Output Primary Navigation
    // =============================================================================

    if ( ! function_exists( 'x_output_primary_navigation' ) ) :
      function x_output_primary_navigation() {

        if ( x_is_one_page_navigation() ) {

          wp_nav_menu( array(
            'menu'           => x_get_one_page_navigation_menu(),
            'theme_location' => 'primary',
            'container'      => false,
            'menu_class'     => 'x-nav x-nav-scrollspy',
            'link_before'    => '<span>',
            'link_after'     => '</span>'
          ) );

        } elseif ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) {

          wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location' => 'primary',
            'container'      => false,
            'menu_class'     => 'x-nav',
            'link_before'    => '<span>',
            'link_after'     => '</span>'
          ) );

        } else {

          echo '<ul class="x-nav"><li><a href="' . home_url( '/' ) . 'wp-admin/nav-menus.php">Assign a Menu</a></li></ul>';

        }

      }
    endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

To get that kind of control you will probably need to create a custom Walker. Take a look at the defaults for [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

```
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);
```

You are going to need to create a new Walker and load it with the `'walker'          => ''` argument. There is [an example toward the middle of the page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_custom_Walker_class), and numerous Q/As here if you search.

Since it looks like you are hacking a theme, I'd suggest creating a child theme, and altering the Walker via the [`wp_nav_menu_args` filter](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L243).

```
$args = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_args', $args );
```